# wit ai node messenger.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'Logger' of undefined

Tags: node.js, wit-ai

I am trying to use wit-node "messenger.js" but once i run it, its giving error logger not found.

https://github.com/asimkh/hellohazzir

```
Review my code
// Setting up our bot
const wit = new Wit({
  accessToken: WIT_TOKEN,
  actions,
  logger: new log.Logger(log.INFO)
});
```

[image]

Comment: log.Logger isn't supposed to be only Logger? Just wondering.

Comment: Its same as ( Line 137) https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/messenger.js